# what's the probability of each subsequent card being larger

Tags: statistics, probability

Imagine a deck of 500 cards numbered from 1 to 500. If all the cards are shuffled randomly and you are asked to pick three cards, one at a time, what's the probability of each subsequent card being larger than the previously drawn card

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. It is more suitable for [statistics.se] instead. You can find more information about this site by taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages. Note that [statistics.se] most likely is not going to do your homework for you either.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about probability and mathematics instead of programming / coding / programming tools / software algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

This looks very much like homework, so here is a numerical result

```
cards=replicate(1e6,sample(1:52,3))
results=apply(cards,2,function(x){
  if (x[1]<x[2] & x[2]<x[3]) {
    return(1)
  } else {
    return(0)
  }
})
mean(results)
[1] 0.166298
```